# Change formula array for every X number of rows in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, integer, countif

I have large number of rows of data in Excel where I need to change the row array of the formula for every 3 rows but I can't figure out how to adjust the formula without an error.

How do I add a formula like this to the formula below?

=INT(((ROW(a1)-1)/11))*1+1

This is the formula I have been using, but I need to change it for every 3 rows.

=IF(COUNTIF($N$4:$N$6, ""), "",MAX($N$4:$N$6))

=IF(COUNTIF($N$7:$N$9, ""), "",MAX($N$7:$N$9))

And so on

Example

I have 3 approvers, if "product" is approved, the date is for the approval date of last said approval, if no approval has been made then the cell is blank. Outcome is what I want to collect from column 3 when product was approved from all 3 approvers which is the newest date of the 3 rows, if one approver has not approved, then I'd like column 4 to be blank.

| Product | Approvers | Dates | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 04.01.2016 | 04.01.2016 |
| A | 2 | 17.12.2015 | 04.01.2016 |
| A | 3 | 21.12.2015 | 04.01.2016 |
| B | 1 | 11.04.2017 | 11.04.2017 |
| B | 2 | 30.01.2017 | 11.04.2017 |
| B | 3 | 04.04.2017 | 11.04.2017 |
| C | 1 |  |  |
| C | 2 | 13.10.2016 |  |
| C | 3 | 14.02.2017 |  |
| D | 1 | 01.03.2022 | 01.03.2022 |
| D | 2 | 02.12.2019 | 01.03.2022 |
| D | 3 | 30.01.2020 | 01.03.2022 |

[Picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wsIL.png)

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I have Excel 2016, and I can't download add ons unless IT approves it.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

To answer the original question, to make your formula change every `n` rows, use `=-MOD(ROW()+c, n)` to adjust this (where 'c' is a constant just to get them in line, if your data starts on row 2 then `c` would be 1).
Your formula for row 2 would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET($N2,-MOD(ROW($N2)+1,3),0,3),""),"",MAX(OFFSET($N2,-MOD(ROW($N2)+1,3),0,3)))
```

Another option, not as direct an answer to the question but potentially useful if the number of products changed in future from 3 to something else, would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(L:L, L2, N:N, ""), "", MAX(IF(L:L=L2, L:L)))
```

and click Ctrl+Shift+Enter after typing that in (because it's an Array formula, see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7), [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/array-formulas-functions-excel/) and [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula)).
The advantage of this approach is that it looks at all rows where the product column is the same (I'm assuming unique products), so no need to limit it to 3 rows per product or have those 3 rows next to each other.

Comment: If you were to upgrade to Excel 2019, 2021, or 365 then you'd have access  to the `MAXIFS` formula, which make option 2 even simpler